# DictWriter big files 'empty'

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pymongo

I have looked at other questions but they all seem to point at not closing the file, that should not be the case with my function. I have a pymongo cursor that retrieves a number of rows. When this is small (around 10,000) there is no problem, it takes the appropriate fields and writes them away. When I do a full query (couple of million rows), it finishes properly (no errors), the file is around 2.1 GB however I cannot open it in my CSV editor, Excel or Notepad++, either they do nothing or say the file is empty. Here is my code:

```
def write_csv(curs, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer = DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=columns, delimiter=';')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in curs:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I pass the pymongo cursor to this file like this:

```
results = wtebt_collection.find(query,projection=proj)
write_csv(results, 'my_file.csv')
```

Can someone explain me why this doesn't work? Also, if there are better approaches to do this, let me know. This is the smaller of the two queries.

Comment: If the file is 2.1 GB, that probably means it's not empty. Have you inspected it with something other than full blown programs? `more file.csv` on the command line or such? Perhaps you're just blowing past your applications' memory limits.

Comment: I'm aware that it's not empty, that was the message from my CSV reader (I'll clarify that in my question). Memory should not be an issue, I have 32 GB and am on 64bit OS, regularly deal with files larger than this (also in the CSV reader). Do you have a suggestion for further inspection in Windows 7?

Comment: Windows 7 I have no idea, but there's gotta be something that lets you read just a few lines of the file (like `more` on *NIX) instead of trying to load it all into memory at once.

Comment: It's actually the same command. It does show the first lines correctly so that is not the case, it maybe doesn't close the file properly? I just tried reading a 4.5 GB csv in my normal reader and there is no problem there.

Comment: Well, I'd confirm that with `tail file.csv`. If the file *looks okay*, then it's likely an issue with the other applications that are trying to open it.

Comment: Hmm, weird it looks like you are right. Reading it with Pandas there is no issue. Thanks

Comment: Some editor's will not handle GB files. Excel used to be limited to Mega-Byte Csv files, I am not sure about the current Excel limit. You can use very memory very quickly in a program; typically the more fancy functions you provide, the more memory is required.